# Implementing MeanshiftFilter to a image causing a discontinuous edge

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, blur

As the graph shows, I implemented 3 kinds of blurring to my source image.
Gaussian & Median blurs look OK, but the Meanshift result confused me.
There are discontinuous areas on the right side.

[image: 3kindblur]

My implemented code is 
`pyrMeanShiftFiltering(src2, dst2, 5, 25, 3);`, and it's still the same after being modified to `pyrMeanShiftFiltering(src2, dst2, 2, 25, 3);`.

So I think it's got nothing to do with Spatial Window Radius.

Can anyone explain why this happened, and how to avoid it for me?

Thanks a lot!

========================================================

8/13

added code:

```
int border = 1;
copyMakeBorder(src2, src2, border, border, border, border, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
```

Unfortunately, it's still the same..

[image: border]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ekran.org/ben/wp/2011/mean-shift-segmentation/) I can see the same effect, so looks like a bug in implementation (looks like convolution edge effect). You can try to add border to image, before applying the filter, and remove border after processing finished (see copyMakeBorder opencv's method).

Comment: Thanks for advice! But the result is showed above.
Some border pixels are merged with near pixel, but some aren't.(I really don't understand why..) The black border is ruined, so i can't remove it after Meanshift.
And the right side area is still the same, although it looks better than original result.

Comment: First: set larger border 10-50 px. not 1 pixel. Second: Why you can't remove border? It have fixed size, just use ROI. Third: try different border types, like mirror for instance.